# How to match strings around a term

Tags: regex

What is the best way to match the following phrases?

- Cumulus
- Cumulus Identity Server
- Cumulus Service
- **LS** Cumulus **Connector**

In other words. What is the best way to deal with that LS and Connector **around** Cumulus, like this rough draft:

```
Cumulus( Identity Server| Service)?|LS Cumulus Connector.
```

Thank you!

Comment: You mean you want to match these 4 phrases? `Cumulus(?:\s+(?:Identity\s+Server|Service))?|LS\s+Cumulus\s+Connector`?

Comment: Yes, but with as little code as possible.

Comment: I doubt you need it.

Comment: Why I wouldn't need it?

Comment: Because you want to match these phrases as a whole, and do not need to get submatches - you do not mention in the question you want to have any specific match structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made your solution work:

```
(Cumulus( Identity Server| Service)?)|(LS Cumulus Connector)
```

The problem in your solution was the space after "Cumulus" - I moved it inside the parenthesis.

Test [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/Mw0p4j/1).

Comment: Thanks about the space issue. But aren't there any optimized alternatives?

Comment: I guess that there are, but you might get a brain fracture trying to read and understand them :) The big issue is that "LS" and "Connector" need to go together - both or none. And they are not near each other. Occasionally, the obvious is better than the optimized.